# Using XSLT to convert Captivate XML Attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I'm aware there are several topics on this question, but none of the ones I've read use the same syntax as this.

I'm trying to pull some Captivate xml result files into SSIS, the problem seems to be that the results are stored inside a value attribute:

```
<Course>
<CompanyName value='Hanover'/>
<DepartmentName value='ICT'/>
<CourseName value='TEST'/>
<LearnerName value='Paul Wilson'/>
<LearnerID value='05757'/>
<LessonName value='ICT Literacy Test'></LessonName>
<QuizAttempts value='1'></QuizAttempts>
<TotalQuestions value='26'></TotalQuestions>
<Result><CoreData><Status value='completed'></Status>
<Location value='30'></Location>
<RawScore value='100'></RawScore>
<MaxScore value='100'></MaxScore>
<MinScore value='0'></MinScore>
<SessionTime value='undefined'></SessionTime>
</CoreData>
<InteractionData><Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:32'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Open_File'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='1916'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:43'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Close_Window'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='10889'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:49'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Open_Outlook'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='5464'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:51'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_New_Email'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='2520'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:54'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_Add_Attachment'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='2008'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:40:57'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='FS_Select_File'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_201611414227'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='1626'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:0'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_Email_Send'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_20161114185131'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='2497'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:10'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_Calendar'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_20161114185131'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='10280'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:34'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Web_Address'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='fill-in'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='www.google.co.uk'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='www.google.co.uk'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='12631'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:43'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Google_Search'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='fill-in'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='hanover housing edinburgh'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='hanover housing edinburgh'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='7074'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:48'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_New_Tab'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016114134626'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='3335'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:51'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Favourites'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016114134626'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='3436'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:53'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Open_Fav'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016114134626'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='1812'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:41:56'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Form_Login'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016114134626'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='1'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='1'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='2340'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:42:13'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='FS_File_Type'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='matching'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='0.A,1.B,2.C,3.D'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='0.A,1.B,2.C,3.D'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='16973'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:42:28'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='FS_Recycle'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='A'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='A'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='13683'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:42:42'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Right_Click'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='A'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='A'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='12293'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:42:57'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Max_Min'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='C'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='C'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='13544'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:43:10'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Window_Close'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='D'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='D'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='10794'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:43:25'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Desktop'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='C'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='C'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='13868'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:43:31'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='WN_Icons'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='B'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='B'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='4159'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:43:47'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='OF_Copying'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='A;B;C'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='A;B;C'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='13813'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:44:3'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='OF_Printing'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='A;B'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='A;B'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='14178'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:44:21'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='IE_Saving'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='B'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='B'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='17168'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:44:33'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_Reply'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='A'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='A'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='9776'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date value='2016/11/23'></Date>
<InteractionTime value='11/23/2016T8:44:41'></InteractionTime>
<InteractionID value='MO_Address'></InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID value='Quiz_2016103113211'></ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType value='choice'></InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse value='B'></CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse value='B'></StudentResponse>
<Result value='C'></Result>
<Weight value='1'></Weight>
<Latency value='6601'></Latency>
<Attempt value='1'></Attempt>
</Interactions>
</InteractionData>
</Result>
</Course>
```

In order to work with SSIS, I need to get it formatted like this:

```
<Course>
<CompanyName>Hanover</CompanyName>
<DepartmentName>ICT</DepartmentName>
<CourseName>TEST</CourseName>
<LearnerName>Paul Wilson</LearnerName>
<LearnerID>05757</LearnerID>
<LessonName>ICT Literacy Test</LessonName>
<QuizAttempts>1</QuizAttempts>
<TotalQuestions>26</TotalQuestions>
<Result>
<CoreData>
<Status>completed</Status>
<Location>30</Location>
<RawScore>100</RawScore>
<MaxScore>100</MaxScore>
<MinScore>0</MinScore>
<SessionTime>undefined</SessionTime>
</CoreData>
<InteractionData>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:32</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Open_File</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>1916</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:43</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Close_Window</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>10889</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:49</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Open_Outlook</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>5464</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:51</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_New_Email</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>2520</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:54</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_Add_Attachment</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>2008</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:40:57</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>FS_Select_File</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_201611414227</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>1626</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:0</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_Email_Send</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_20161114185131</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>2497</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:10</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_Calendar</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_20161114185131</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>10280</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:34</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Web_Address</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>fill-in</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>www.google.co.uk</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>www.google.co.uk</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>12631</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:43</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Google_Search</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>fill-in</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>hanover housing edinburgh</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>hanover housing edinburgh</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>7074</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:48</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_New_Tab</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016114134626</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>3335</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:51</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Favourites</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016114134626</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>3436</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:53</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Open_Fav</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016114134626</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>1812</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:41:56</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Form_Login</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016114134626</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>1</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>1</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>2340</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:42:13</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>FS_File_Type</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>matching</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>0.A,1.B,2.C,3.D</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>0.A,1.B,2.C,3.D</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>16973</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:42:28</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>FS_Recycle</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>A</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>A</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>13683</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:42:42</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Right_Click</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>A</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>A</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>12293</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:42:57</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Max_Min</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>C</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>C</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>13544</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:43:10</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Window_Close</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>D</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>D</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>10794</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:43:25</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Desktop</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>C</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>C</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>13868</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:43:31</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>WN_Icons</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>B</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>B</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>4159</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:43:47</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>OF_Copying</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>A;B;C</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>A;B;C</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>13813</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:44:3</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>OF_Printing</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>A;B</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>A;B</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>14178</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions>
<Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:44:21</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>IE_Saving</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>B</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>B</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>17168</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:44:33</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_Reply</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>A</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>A</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>9776</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
<Interactions><Date>2016/11/23</Date>
<InteractionTime>11/23/2016T8:44:41</InteractionTime>
<InteractionID>MO_Address</InteractionID>
<ObjectiveID>Quiz_2016103113211</ObjectiveID>
<InteractionType>choice</InteractionType>
<CorrectResponse>B</CorrectResponse>
<StudentResponse>B</StudentResponse>
<Result>C</Result>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Latency>6601</Latency>
<Attempt>1</Attempt>
</Interactions>
</InteractionData>
</Result>
</Course>
```

I'm a complete neophyte at XSLT (and StackOverflow it seems) and would appreciate any help. The closest I've got is encasing each value inside a  element.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Start with an identity transform, then add a template matching elements with a `value` attribute (`match="*[@value]"`), output a copy of the element (`xsl:copy`) and inside that copy output the value of the attribute (`xsl:value-of select="@value"`).

Comment: @PaulWilson Given your clarification, I suggest you follow Daniel Haley's advice.